# Python image based program

Tags: python, image

i have one question. Working on a project right now and i can't really find out if there is a way to make screenshots into a specific position of the screen, compare the screenshots with other's (probably from a database) and if screenshot match with one from database, run a specific script for it (there are like 120 scripts or so), everything should be into a loop and if the image change again run another script from them. If someone know some sources that can help me or ideas i would be glad to read them. Thanks ^^

Comment: This is way too broad. Try something and come ask Stack Overflow when you are really facing an issue. But yes there are ways to do what you want...

Comment: Well, i don't know from where to start with it so..

Comment: search : "python take screenshot", then "python truncate image", then "python compare two images (ssim)", ...